# Adding JLabel text over JLabel Icon. Using the same JLabel text

Tags: java, swing, text, jlabel

Sorry about the title being vague but I couldn't think of what I wanted to do in the title.
Anyway, for text over image, I have used a JLabel text and added it to the Icon.

```
    JLabel icon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon);
    icon.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(icon);

    JLabel text = new JLabel();
    text.setText(language.getString("translation"));
    text.setLocation(10, 10);
    text.setSize(text.getPreferredSize());
    icon.add(text);
```

I am doing i18n for my app and every time I switch locales, it adds the same JLabel to the previous one so you can see the text on top of each other. How do I use the same Jlabel instead of adding a new one on top?

Thanks

Comment: You could post an SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example) to make your question more understadable or You can post an Image to elucidate =)

Comment: See my answer.. If you want the text overlaps the icon =)

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want to create is a JLabel with custom icon

You should create a JLabel and set it's icon, like this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(language.getString("translation"));
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(/* path of your icon */));
```

And if you want fix the text overlap, you should set the text alignment
like this:

`lblText.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);`

Comment: It is possible to set it between `CENTER` to `TOP` location ?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the text label as a field of class and just call setText() rather than recreating/adding them.

Answer (score 2):

You can set text over imageLabel using setText("abc") and can position the text using setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER) and setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM) methods.

```
dragLabel[i].setText("default");
           dragLabel[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
           dragLabel[i].setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
```